# When I am running my first android app using Genymotion emulator its giving error unfortunately "app name" has stopped. Please help me

Tags: java, android

I am giving the details of all my files below.Please check them and let me know where I am doing the mistake due to which the error that the "unfortunately "app name" has stopped" error is coming when I am running my first android app using android SDK. Since I am a beginner in android development Please explain the solution nicely.

My MainActivity.java file :

```
package com.example.sunny.myfirstapp;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView textView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.greetings_view);
}
public void showGreetings(View view)
{
    String message= "welcome to my app";
    textView.setText(message);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

My activity_main.xml file is as follows:

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
     android:id="@+id/greetings_view">
      <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="greetings here"
      android:id="@+id/greetings_view"

      />
     <Button
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="show greetings"
      android:layout_below="@+id/greetings_view"
      android:onClick="My button"
     android:id="@+id/greetings_view"
    />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

My AndroidManifest.xml file :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.sunny.myfirstapp"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="5"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.sunny.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

My logcat :

```
        06-26 10:37:23.137  31265-31265/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
        06-26 10:37:24.013  31265-31265/com.example.sunny.myfirstapp D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
        06-26 10:37:24.021  31265-31265/com.example.sunny.myfirstapp W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa62be288)
        06-26 10:37:24.025  31265-31265/com.example.sunny.myfirstapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sunny.myfirstapp/com.example.sunny.myfirstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try like this , it will Work

```
 package com.example.sunny.myfirstapp;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.greetings_view);

        String message= "welcome to my app";
        textView.setText(message);
    }
    }
```

Remove from **android:id="@+id/greetings_view"** Relative Layout , You given that id in Two places **TextvieW** and **Relative Layout**

simple textview xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/greetings_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: remove that  android:id="@+id/greetings_view" from relative layout it will work try

Comment: in button also you given same id , remove that or change the differnt id in button

Answer (score 1):

all your views have the same ID `greetings_view`, elements must have no ID (blank) or different IDs.

ps.: in the future, the relevant log cat is the Stacktrace, is the part that have the direct message related to your crash. The log you posted is just some random stuff from your phone.

Comment: changing ID is not helping its giving the same error

Comment: you didn't say what is the error. All I could do is a best guess

Comment: now try to read it yourself: "ClassCastException: RelativeLayout cannot be cast to TextView"

Comment: change android:id="@+id/greetings_view"> of the relativelayout to something else